# How do I create a margins on Google maps?

Tags: html, css, google-maps

How do I create boundaries or margins on google maps on HTML5, here is an example of what I'm trying to achieve.
http://transpad.in/bwssb/
The colored markings is what I want to create, can this be done using css or is there a google api for it.
Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you call margin is perimeter of a polygon you can set the color of the border of a poligon this way

```
// Define the LatLng coordinates for the polygon's path.
var triangleCoords = [
  {lat: 25.774, lng: -80.190},
  {lat: 18.466, lng: -66.118},
  {lat: 32.321, lng: -64.757},
  {lat: 25.774, lng: -80.190}
];

 // Construct the polygon.
 var triangle = new google.maps.Polygon({
   paths: triangleCoords,
   strokeColor: '#FF0000',
   strokeOpacity: 0.8,
   strokeWeight: 2,
   fillColor: '#FF0000',
   fillOpacity: 0.35
 });
```

strokeColor, strokeWeight and strokeOpacity are the attribute for define the border of a poligon,  fillColor and fillOpacity are for the content aspect